Flutter Refresh indicator over PageVIew
In Flutter I would use a refreshIndicator to refresh a list made by an horrizontal pageview (a list of scrollable cards), but it seems that refreshIndicator works only with listView / gridView.
Has anyone faced this problem?

Refresh Indicator works with PageView its just that it does not work with horizontal scrolling. see this . This thread contain the workaround which you can implement to show refresh indicator on horizontal pull

So there is no way to keep the same ui of the refreshindicator

try this custom_refresh_indicator: ^3.1.0, it might work for you

Thanks this library is for me, I’m sad that there is no native solution

So i tried this custom_refresh_indicator: ^3.1.0, and it works for your case, you can try running below code
class ApiWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApiWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApiWidget> createState() => _ApiWidgetState();
}

class _ApiWidgetState extends State<ApiWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomMaterialIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {}, // Your refresh logic
        indicatorBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, IndicatorController controller) {
          return const Icon(
            Icons.ac_unit,
            color: Colors.blue,
            size: 30,
          );
        },
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                index.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

